# How To Enable PHP Zip module?

Tags: php, wordpress, module, zip, themes

I just installed a new theme to my site and am now attempting to load the demo site pages that came with the theme. I am getting an error message before I ever even attempt to do anything that says the following:

Oops, Unyson Backup requires PHP Zip module but it is not enabled on your server. If you are not familiar with PHP Zip module, please contact your hosting provider.​

Can anyone tell me how to enable PHP Zip module im using virtualmin i don't use a regular cpanel
Thank you

im looking for php but

Comment: You should have access to the server's SSH. If it's a linux server, try installing `php-zip` package. If you don't have SSH access, try contacting your hosting provider to download and install the aforementioned package